# Infinite While Loop In C

Tags: c

this code is creating me an infinite loop i want to follow some steps getting the number debut to 0 adn printing how much steps it tooks the program to do it

```
    int debut,i;
    printf("de (>= 1) ? ");
    do
    {            
        scanf("%d",&debut);
    } 
    while (debut < 1);

    int fin;
    printf("a >=  <<  << ) ? ");
    do 
    {            
        scanf("%d",&fin) ;
    } 
    while (fin < debut);

   for (;debut<=fin;debut++){
       i=0;
       while(debut!=0)
       {
           if(debut%3==0)
           {
               debut+=4;
           }
           else if (debut%3!=0 && debut%4==0){
               debut/=2;
           }
           else if (debut%3!=0 && debut%4!=0)
           {
               debut-=1;
           }
           i+=1;

       }
       printf("%d\n->%d",debut,i);    
       }
```

Comment: If your issue has been resolved, you should mark one of the answers as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

```
for(debut<=fin;debut++) {
    while(debut!=0) {
        //do stuff
    }
    //debut == 0, debut <= fin
}
```

Okay, massive edit to my answer.  I was looking at the wrong loop.

In order to enter the `for` loop, `debut` must be `<=fin`.  Any time that `fin` is `>0`, and the `for` loop is entered, you'll be stuck in the `for` loop.

You're stuck in the `while` loop until `debut == 0` returns `true`.  As long as `debut++ <= fin`, you're stuck in the `for` loop.  You're modifying `debut` in the `while` loop, but `fin` remains the same value.  So the `while` loop reduces `debut` to `0` and the `for` loop goes to the next iteration every time.

Comment: not true (in theory) : there is debut -= 1. Doing so 2^32 times or so should do it

Comment: I don't think you understand the problem here. This looks like a syracuse sequence. No proof of infinite loop or not. Changing to > 0 should not do anything

Comment: @MohamedBensalah Now check the answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Short Answer**: I suspect that you intended your while loop to work on a *copy* of `debut`, and not `debut` itself.

---

- Let's assume that `debut == 3` and `fin == 5`.
- We execute the first iteration of the for loop, which involves a complete walkthrough of the while loop.
- After the while loop, we have `debut == 0`, `fin == 5`, and `i == 12`.
- We then print some information.
- However, we are now going to iterate on the for loop again. `debut` has been decreased to `0`, because of the work we did, and so each time we run through this code, at the end of the for loop iteration, we are going to have a `debut == 0`, which will cause the for loop to never exit.

---

It may be more helpful to show this inline with the code...

```
for (;debut<=fin;debut++){
    // Let's assume we get here. We can assume some sane debut and fin values,
    // such as the 3 and 5 suggested above.

    int i=0;
    while (debut != 0) {
        // Stuff happens that makes debut go to zero.
    }

    // To get to this point, we __know__ that debut == 0.
    // We know this because that's the condition in the while loop.

    // Therefore, when we do the comparison in the for loop above for the
    // next iteration, it will succeed over and over again, because debut
    // has been changed to zero.

    printf("%d->%d\n",debut,i);
}
```

---

Personally, I suspect you're looking for the number of iterations for a set of numbers. This to me sounds like a perfect place to use a function. The code I would suggest would look something like this.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int iterations(int debut) {
    int i = 0;

    while(debut!=0)
    {
        if(debut%3==0)
        {
            debut+=4;
        }
        else if (debut%3!=0 && debut%4==0){
            debut/=2;
        }
        else if (debut%3!=0 && debut%4!=0)
        {
            debut-=1;
        }

        i+=1;
    }

    return i;
}

int main() {
    int debut = 3;
    int fin = 5;

    for (;debut<=fin;debut++) {
        printf("%d -> %d\n", debut, iterations(debut));
    }
}
```

---

Also, just for the sake of noting things, please note that in the example code that I've given at the end, I removed all of the input scanf code. It's not related to your actual problem, and it reduces the total amount of code that anyone needs to scan to understand where your problem is.

Comment: Beat me to the punch! :)